# What was the timing of Lockwood's falling out?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

It's established in *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom* that Benjamin Lockwood was an early partner of John Hammond, but they parted ways over a disagreement involving Lockwood's granddaughter

> Actually a clone of Lockwood's deceased daughter

But John Hammond died in 1998, and Maisie isn't anywhere near 20 years old. Unless Lockwood

> starting the cloning research a decade or so before he succeeded

I don't see how the timing of the events works. And the above explanation has its own problem, as it would seem difficult to hide that

> Maisie was born multiple years after her "mother's" death

Is the timeline of Hammond and Lockwood's relationship established?

Comment: Re your second point: hide it from who? There were only about three people in the house other than Maisie, and they already knew. Maisie herself was clearly interested in answers, but seemingly hadn't been told much about her mother. And for someone as rich as Lockwood, getting the necessary documents forged probably wouldn't have been too difficult.

Comment: From Maisie for one. Lies covering a discrepancy of several years could be hard to keep straight between three different people in a lot of conversations with a curious child about her mother. Also from visitors: they didn't try to hide the fact that Lockwood had a granddaughter from Claire, but the car crash where a m(b?)illionare's daughter died is probably a matter of public record.